# update setState instance in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks, use-state

I am trying to fetch images stored on firebase storage and display in react native app. the functions works to get the download URL of images but it doesn't merge previous state and update component, it just displays in only one image (due to useState). so as each image is fetched it displays the image in the same image component instead of creating a new component to display in

Code:

```
import React, {setState, useState} from 'react';
import {DrawerActions, useNavigation} from '@react-navigation/native';

const Gallery = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const [downloadUrl, setDownloadUrl] = useState({url: undefined});
  console.log(`URL should be undefined at this point ${downloadUrl}`);

  function listFilesAndDirectories(reference, pageToken) {
    return reference.list({pageToken}).then(result => {
      result.items.forEach(ref => {
        ref.getDownloadURL().then(url => {
          // console.log(`Image URL is:\n ${url}`);
          setDownloadUrl({url: url});
        });
      });

      if (result.nextPageToken) {
        return listFilesAndDirectories(reference, result.nextPageToken);
      }

      return Promise.resolve();
    });
  }

  const storageReference = firebase
    .storage()
    .refFromURL('gs://ab404.appspot.com/images');

  listFilesAndDirectories(storageReference).then(() => {
    console.log('Started listing image download urls');
  });

  return (
    <>
      <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" />
      <SafeAreaView>
        <View style={SharedStyles.header}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => {
              navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer());
            }}>
            <Hamburg />
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <Header title="Gallery" />
        </View>
        <ScrollView contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic">
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
              <View>
                <Text>
                  Welcome to the Abulad Gallery! Come back for more content....
                </Text>
                <Image
                  source={{uri: downloadUrl.url}}
                  style={styles.fetchedImage}
                />
              </View>
            </View>
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </>
  );
};
```

I have tried using the spread operator to get previous state and update as needed but I get an `invalid attempt to spread a non-iterable instance`

I need a way to make images appear in their component while updating url
Thanks

Comment: there doesn't seem to be anything in your code indicating that `ref.getDownloadUrl` exists.

Comment: It does. 'ref' is an argument of the arrow function. Can you share the whole page? If I understand you correctly you want to show grid of images instead of just one? Your problem I assume is in the return function. you should save all the images url's and then map them to Image.

Comment: yes. The images are meant to show separately i.e as each URL is downloaded, it is displayed In its own image component but my code only updates the single image component